# jQuery UI show() effect is not expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to reproduce on `show()` the same scale effect run on `hide()`. I'm using the same parameters, but the effect is not the same:

```
$('.div1').show('scale', {
   direction: "horizontal",
   duration: 1000
});

$('.div2').hide('scale', {
   direction: "horizontal",
   duration: 1000
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AUM6d/305/

Comment: Which scale direction are you wanting - horizontal or both?  If you use "both", the show and hide effects are the same.

Comment: I agree it does look like direction: "horizontal" on show() doesn't actually work. I suggest filing a bug report with the Jquery UI people.

Comment: @SurrealDreams I want the show() has the opposite animation that hide()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `from` attribute and achieve what you wanted:

```
$('.div1').show('scale', {
        direction: "horizontal" ,
        from: { width: "0"}
       },
    1000
);
```

That way you tell it to start from 0 width and expand from there.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUM6d/309/)

Comment: It's interesting - people are saying that horizontal is buggy, but you really just have to be a little more specific with it.

Comment: @Adjit True. Hard to blame them though, the documentation isn't that clear/informative.

Answer (score 1):

If the effect is acceptable, try this:

```
$('.div1').show('scale', {
   direction: "both",
   duration: 1000
});

$('.div2').hide('scale', {
   direction: "both",
   duration: 1000
});
```

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/AUM6d/307/

It's slightly different, but it works.  From my testing (and the jQueryUI demo page) it looks like `direction: 'horizontal'` is buggy.

Comment: Sorry, but I need horizontal direction. I will try using CSS3 scaleX. Thanks.